# Built-in router in iOS app

Tags: ios, cocoa, routes, network-programming, network-protocols

I need to do something like a built-in router in iOS app. It will be manage all in-app traffic and share it with iOS devices that connected to this network . Is it possible in iOS? And what instruments should I use?